# RavenDB Querying on ID

Tags: ravendb

I have a Model called **Post**, which has a field called **Slug**. I've marked this field with the attribute [ID] and changed the FindIdentityProperty Convention in RavenDB such that it considers the property marked with [ID] as the Identity of the document.

Now I want to fetch all posts that have slugs that start with the character G, do I need to create an index like this :

```
from Post in docs.Posts
select new { Slug = Post.Slug }
```

or like this

```
from Post in docs.Posts
select new { Id = Post.Id }
```

or do I use the index that RavenDB internally should have since I'm querying on ID.
I understand that RavenDB has the ID property indexed somewhere so that a `Session.Load<Post>("SomeID")` is possible.

The 1st option can be defined in code in C# as an AbstractIndexCreationTask because C# understands that Slug is a field of Post, but does not work as it is "string"ified into RavenDB like this :  (when Index Creation happens)

```
from Post in docs.Posts
select new { Slug = Post.Slug }
```

becomes

```
docs.Posts
    .Select(Post => new {Slug = Post.Slug })
```

You can see this when you look in the SL-UI, after indexes are created.

And this does **NOT** work because ( as shown in the SL-UI of the DB ) the JSON representation of the Post, there is no name-value pair like `"Slug":"Some-Slug"`. Since it's the ID it is shown *above* the document, and in the @metadata it can be seen as the value of **_document_id**

The latter one does work, but only when defined as a string, like this in C#

```
public class Post_ById : AbstractIndexCreationTask
    {
        public override IndexDefinition CreateIndexDefinition()
        {
            return new IndexDefinition
                       {
                           Map = "from Post in docs.Posts select new { Id = Post.Id}"
                       };
        }
    }
```

I suspect when Raven gets queries that contain the string "**Id**", it automatically takes it to mean that it's a query on **[@metadata][_document_id]**.

No LINQ goodness here - looks very brittle, won't survive a refactor of the domain name. **Id** is not a field of Post, but this index did allow me to do what I wanted, namely, "*fetch all posts that have slugs that start with the character G*". And I hate defining indexes for Ids when DB should already have such an index.

Answer (score 3):

Hm, we actually use the same conventions in AbstractIndexCreationTask as well, so that should work.
At any rate, the id of the document can always be accessed using __document_id

Comment: So you are using the second option as well, D'you think it is wise that I'm creating Post_ByID and I have to create indexes on ID for the Post, Passphrase and a few other domains. ANY person who decides to use an attribute(annotation) to mark a property as ID and change the FindIdentityConvention will face the same problem as me, an index such as Post_BySlug won't work.